# Tabulator Load CSV data and Validate

Tags: tabulator

I am new to java script, working on prototype to validate loaded csv data from local file and save to sql.
Created page with two buttons one for Loading file another of Validating.
when validate is clicked after loading csv it triggers as expected.

```
let csvalid = table.validate();
console.log(csvalid);
```

output in console show proxy(s) for rows which failed validation (shows true for rows validation passed), need help with sample code in getting only rows which failed validations.

JS Fiddle link: [JS Fiddle Tabulator](https://jsfiddle.net/technofreaks/2ka1oxr4/47/)

Need to help with example code to further improving validation by providing button to show only rows where validation failed and adding tooltip information.

- Using columns title: and field: in order to save imported data to sql database after validation using php backend.

Comment: JS Fiddle Link was incorrect, updated link.